# What stops a method from calling itself?

Tags: objective-c, recursion

When I implement a method like this:

```
-(void)exampleMethod{
    [self exampleMethod];
}
```

and run it, I get `EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8)`.

When I call a method or function in the method, it calls itself for a much longer time before crashing.

Here is an example:

```
-(void)exampleMethod{
    NSLog(@"Example Was Run");
    [self exampleMethod];
}
```

**What logic happens at runtime to cause this behavior?**

Comment: *Oxford's English Dictionary* - recursion - see recursion.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying the 2nd bit of code never crashes? It should when you eventually run out of stack space, just like the 1st.

Comment: @rmaddy no, The second one crashes after about a minute of running, but the first crashes almost instantaneously. Are you suggesting that the first uses more stack space faster?

Comment: @68cherries See Chuck's answer. Yes, the 1st is quicker due to not having to log anything.

Comment: You really should clarify your question. As written you make it sound like the 2nd bit of code never crashes.

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect what I am asking. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If I run the method on the simulator in release mode, neither implementations of the method crash...

Comment: @68cherries: In Release mode, the compiler replaces the recursive call by a jump instruction. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will call itself over and over either way. This is an infinite recursion, which in a language like Objective-C will eventually cause you to run out of stack space and crash. The difference is that the version with the print statement is much slower (because printing is extremely slow compared to calling a function), so it will take a lot longer before it blows the stack. (That is, it will take more time as measured by a wall clock, not that it will get more iterations. Each iteration is slower, so it takes longer to get to the number of iterations that kills your program.)